# NumPy ndarray of ndarray of float64 not flattening

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a pandas dataframe with a column called 'corr'.  Each row contains an ndarray of float64.  The following code is giving me issues:

```
import pandas as pd
experimentDataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'corr': [np.array([1.0,2.0]),np.array([3.0,4.0]),np.array([5.0,6.0])]})
corr = experimentDataFrame['corr'].to_numpy(copy=True)
print ([type(corr), corr.shape])
print ([type(corr[0]), corr[0].shape])
print ([type(corr[0][0]), corr[0][0].shape])
corr = corr.flatten()
print ([type(corr), corr.shape])
print ([type(corr[0]), corr[0].shape])
print ([type(corr[0][0]), corr[0][0].shape])
```

The output of which is

```
[<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (3,)]
[<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (2,)]
[<class 'numpy.float64'>, ()]
[<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (3,)]
[<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (2,)]
[<class 'numpy.float64'>, ()]
```

I've also tried `corr.ravel()` and `corr.reshape(-1)` instead of `flatten` with no difference.  And I've tried corr.reshape(6) but I get, `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 35 into shape (6,)`.

What I'm expecting is that after flattening, `corr[0]` should be a float64 and not still an ndarray.  My strong suspicion is that since corr is an ndarray of ndarrays of **unknown length**, flatten (and the rest) doesn't work.  Is there a function that will work without iterating manually?

Comment: Of course, you **already have a flat array**, `corr.shape` is `(35,)` which is flat. The problem here is that youve created an array of `dtype=object`. Really, you should consider representing your data in a different way. But in any case, you can just do something like `np.ndarray([x for arr in experimentDataFrame['corr'] for x in arr.ravel()])`. It isn't exactly clear what you have, since you haven't provided a [mcve]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, If you check [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html), array.flatten returns "A copy of the input array, flattened to one dimension.". If you start with an array of 107 elements, why should `flatten` turn that into a single float?

Comment: or maybe just `np.concatenate([arr.ravel() for arr in experimentDataFrame['corr']])`

Comment: thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, both work.  I will edit the question to provide a minimal reproducible example.  you suggested I should represent my data differently, can you elaborate?  also, I get that the problem was that `dtype=object` but I couldn't figure out how to see that this was the case (other than shape being `(35,)` instead of `(35,107)`.

Comment: @EricStimpson you can just check `corr.dtype`

Comment: I meant that generally speaking, having `numpy.ndarray` objects inside a column of `pandas` with `dtype=object` should be reconsidered. It may be the simplest solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `experimentDataFrame['corr'].to_numpy(copy=True)` is **already flat**, the shape is `(35,)`. You have a `dtype=object` array.

You just want something like:

```
corr = np.concatenate([arr.ravel() for arr in experimentDataFrame['corr']])
```

Possibly, you can just do:

```
corr = np.concatenate(experimentDataFrame['corr'].tolist())
```

If all the inner arrays in your column are already flat. It isn't clear that is the case from your question, but either of those should work.

EDIT:

And actually, you don't need `.tolist`, just:

```
corr = np.concatenate(experimentDataFrame['corr'])
```

works.